# The function is running wrong on a second time even when its not static

Tags: c, missing-data

i have made a function of a building that create two buildings now on the second building it hops over some parameters from some reason... why?
now i checked the code a few times and im not using any static varbs so it should not do it... than why it remembers when there is a second run?

**UPDATE** i did that as said but now its only return false... any help will help

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
//defines
#define SIZE 30
#define Q_SIZE 4
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
struct shape
    {
    char name[SIZE];   /* name of the shape */
    int edgeNum;       /* number of edges */
    char sPol[Q_SIZE]; /* if the shape is a regular polygrom */
    };
int shapeMaker();
int main(void)
{
    int check;
    check = shapeMaker();
    if (check == TRUE)
{
    printf("the two shapes are equals!\n");
}
    else if (check == FALSE)
{
    printf("the two shapes are not equals!\n");
}
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}

int shapeMaker()
{
struct shape firstShape;    
struct shape secondShape;

printf("please enter the first shape name: ");
fgets(secondShape.name, SIZE, stdin);
secondShape.name[strcspn(secondShape.name, "\n")] = 0;
printf("\nnow please enter the number of Edges: ");
scanf("%d", &secondShape.edgeNum);
printf("\nis the shape is regular polygom (yes/no)? ");
scanf("%s", secondShape.sPol);
getchar();
printf("\nplease enter the second  shape name: ");
fgets(secondShape.name, SIZE, stdin);
secondShape.name[strcspn(secondShape.name, "\n")] = 0;
printf("\nnow please enter the number of Edges: ");
scanf("%d", &secondShape.edgeNum);
printf("\nis the shape is regular polygom (yes/no)? ");
scanf("%s", secondShape.sPol);
if (firstShape.name == secondShape.name && firstShape.edgeNum ==      secondShape.edgeNum && firstShape.sPol == secondShape.sPol)
{
    return TRUE;
}
else
{
    return FALSE;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `fflush(stdin);` at the beginning of shapeMaker and after fgets

Comment: from some reason the buffer get wierd chars... if i make a compare it allwase return false even if its true...

Comment: when using fgets sometimes the buffer for stdin (the keyboard in this case) keeps trash data and next time it gets called it will read the trash that is why it doesnt wait for a new entry and just reads the trash with the fflush(stdin) you are clearing all the buffer for stdin